# large Black background display in every context menu and popup in ubuntu 14.10 LTS

Tags: unity, upgrade, 16.04, 14.10

Yesterday I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu from 14.10 to 16.04LTS and due to that there seems to be a Graphical error in the UI.

Every context menu and popup has a large black background.

Below is the command I used to upgrade my Ubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get install dist-upgrade
```

I've attached screenshots of the problem,  please help me find a solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using an nvidia graphics card?